# How to select a region in a Windows Forms PictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I want to get a part of picture in a PictureBox by allowing the user to select
a rectangular region (similar to how it can be done in Photoshop with selection tool).

How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to draw a rectangle or lines based on where they clicked and dragged.  Your starting point would be the mouse x, y and then you would get the last point from mouse release x, y.

Answer (score 0):

Catch the mouse events on the Picture Box to define your selection rectangle and use `Graphics.DrawRectangle` to draw your selection rectangle in the Paint Event of the Picture Box.